# Quantum experiment design question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Is there a way to design a double-slit experiment such that, if you put a detector in one place it indicates collapse, and in another case it indicates superposition, and you can extract information about which path was taken?

For instance, if the particles are acting like waves, then any part of the region directly behind the band between the two slits should not receive light, right? But if they're acting like waves, then there should be light traveling behind that band.  Similarly, to the direct right of the right slit, there should be a space which would only be reached if the particle went to that right side and was in wave form.

So, theoretically if you placed some algae in that region, it should grow if the collapse doesn't happen, but it should grow at a slower rate or not at all if the collapse does happen, correct?  In this way could we not determine whether the algae counts as an "observer" for the purposes of collapse?  I guess we have to be careful because there's a little bit of a catch-22 because if all the algae dies then there's no observer anymore so the light would come back.  Also if we just put the algae back at the screen then it has no information about the path taken, so shouldn't cause collapse.

Alternatively are there any places along the direct path from the emitter to the screen that should destructively interfere if the particles are in wave form?  Could we place these algae dishes in such a way that at the end we can test the hypothesis of whether algae counts as an observer?  Of course the entire algae colony could be in superposition until a human looks, so it can't completely rule out the idea that humans are the ultimate observers, but if algae grows in the place that indicates collapse, or the place that doesn't indicate collapse, or both equally that could give us some insight, and we could even potentially weight the amounts to determine the relative absorption rates if we devise an experiment that predicts something other than 100% this or 100% that.

Is there a more solid way to design this experiment?

Comment: Why algae? Why not nano detectors?

Comment: Well, all life tends to have locally reduced entropy... behaving wildly differently from non-life.  Life also all happens to store information.. So I was trying to explore the cause of that.  I was thinking any living system can be considered an observer.  It comes from some ideas that are probably similarly wrong, but are interesting to explore... basically I have this thought that information allows living systems to absorb energy (aka "h-bars) from surrounding systems, and use that energy impulse (Joules*seconds) to keep a certain amount of mass entangled to it for a certain amount of time

Comment: maybe entangled isn't the right word and "entrained" is better.  But the idea is that the more mass that's in the living system, the more information it can store as well by using some of the h-bars to constrain the positions of that mass. So I was thinking that the "observation" effect that supposedly requires consciousness actually just requires any living system to record information about it, because then the photon becomes entrained into that living system.  But of course as it turns out, inert matter can do that too.  So anyway back to the drawing board on some of that lol.

Answer (score 1):

According to your hypothesis of human observation mattering, you can set up identically-prepared petri dishes with identical always-on webcams on each dish, and regularly observe the output of half the webcams on some schedule (or livestream them and get people to watch it 24/7 somehow).

At the end of some interval, there should be some difference between the observed dishes and the unobserved dishes. Or not.

Comment: Yes, that's a good addition.  Just to clarify, my actual belief is that human observation wouldn't matter and that the algae are proper "observers" in their own right that can cause collapse, but either way I think this experiment has the potential to give evidence one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with this idea:

First, I know people go on about a conscious observer mattering, but it doesn't. Such an idea has never been proven experimentally, and if you could just prove that, much simpler fact (not whether or not bacteria=humans), you would already get your nobel prize. Consider watching [this lecture series](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-421-atomic-and-optical-physics-i-spring-2014/resources/lecture-21-two-photon-excitation-ii-and-coherence-i/) (the ones about coherence) to get a better understanding of what ruins coherence and therefore removes the interference pattern. If you have a detector that ruins coherence between the parts of the wavefunction going through either slit, it doesn't matter if a human (or bacteria) actually reads the result showing on that detector. It's the interaction between the particle and the detector that ruins the particle's ability to make an interference pattern with the part of the wavefunction that didn't go through the detector (specifically because the detector introduces a random phase).

Second, I don't think there's any interesting place you can put your bacteria - assuming it absorbs the radiation - which is what would harm it. Are you aware that interference is a phenomenon that only happens far from the slits? In a typical description of the double slit experiment, light/electrons aren't ever stopped from going through one slit entirely by interference. So putting the bacteria near one slit will just measure how much light goes through that slit, which is in no way affected by interference with light that goes through the other slit. If you put bacteria in a dark fringe of the interference pattern far from the slits, then the bacteria is doing the same thing that a sheet of paper would - collapsing the wavefunction and determining whether or not photons land in that spot.

Comment: A few minor notes: (1) I was thinking the algae would absorb the light, not be destroyed by it.  (2) I know that the interference pattern shows up on a screen some distance away, but I figured there were regions of more or less constructive or destructive interference along the way.   

"If you put bacteria in a dark fringe of the interference pattern far from the slits, then the bacteria is doing the same thing that a sheet of paper would" <-- ok I see.  would it make a difference if it was a quantum eraser setup instead?

Comment: In the context of my first point, "quantum eraser" experiments restore coherence by removing the effect of the first detector. This works with light because "the first detector" isn't so much a detector as it is a polarizer. Then another waveplate or polarizer in the other direction or something returns the light to its original polarization and it again interferes. I think (not totally sure) that no such thing could be done if the first polarizer was replaced with algae - because there isn't anything (like a waveplate) that can undo the algae's effect on the light.

Comment: What you say is true about there being different regions along the way with constructive and destructive interference. Putting somehow-transparent bacteria somewhere along the path might be the direction to look, but I'm still quite sure this would have the same effect as a semi-transparent piece of plastic. It would slightly change the interference pattern further down by introducing random phases to photons that interact with the semi-transparent thing.

Comment: OK and presumably this decoherence can happen whether we know what's causing it or not?  So we don't need to somehow take the body into account to "observe" the decoherence? I guess from what I've heard of quantum computers having trouble maintaining coherent states, that must be the case. 

OK I think I get it, thanks!  Big misundersanding on my part.

Comment: @scl Some points for clarification: 1) Your algae detector cell is either going to absorb, scatter or shift phase of the photon, absorb means there is no more photon, scatter means there is no more "interference" pattern, shift (transparency required) means the pattern gets shifted for that one photon.  2) If we do an experiment we find all photons go to the bright areas in the "interference" pattern .... there are no photons in the dark areas, the algae dies here.

Comment: @scl We say photons superimpose in the EM field, but we can never observe this directly.  Two  photons traveling together but perfectly out of phase still have the same energy as 2 photons traveling in phase ... if the out of phase photons interact with matter (algae) they will be likely scattered and absorbed by the next algae cell or cells.  Best not to think of photons as particles (unless your working on the Standard Model) .... better to think of photons as localized energy/waves in the EM field.

Comment: @scl Physicists call collapse for a photon wave function typically when it is absorbed, at the screen for example.  Superposition (where the photons are out pf phase) is not collapse .. your question kind of implied this.

Comment: @scl Coherence has 2 features: 1) all the photons are very similar (frequency/phase typically, and let's not forget polarization), 2) The apparatus has a big influence on how we observe coherence, when we set mirrors in a laser cavity we can produce/select similar photons and as well control the shape of the beam ..... in a slit experiment the apparatus has an affect as well .... we can say the photons are coherent with the apparatus.   Mess with the apparatus and you can cause more coherence or less, called decoherence.

Comment: @scl to better understand the DSE it may be best to consider virtual fields.  For example the excited electron in the atom is already interacting with the EM field even before the photon is emitted.  Virtual fields are forces (no energy) but they do superimpose, example virtual photons are just placeholders to explain electrostatic forces .... but they are needed to explain the real momentum felt by charged objects.

Comment: turns out it's a theory already... integrated information theory.